# SelectList won't pass its value to Controller

Tags: apex

I have a selectList on a VF page and I want it to update a value in the Controller. But it doesn't seem to want to.

Can someone give me an idea of why it won't?

In Controller

```
public static String distance {get;set;}

public static List<SelectOption> getdistList() {
    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
    options.add(new SelectOption('1000','25km'));
    options.add(new SelectOption('5000','50km'));
    options.add(new SelectOption('10000','100km'));
    return options;
}
```

In VF page

```
<apex:form >
    <apex:commandButton value="Back" action="{!backToContact}"/>
</apex:form>

<apex:form >

    Radius: 

    <apex:selectList value="{!distance}" multiselect="false" size="1">
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!distList}" ></apex:selectOptions>  
        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" oncomplete="initialize();" reRender="Form"/>
    </apex:selectList>

    {!distance}

</apex:form>
```

I do set the value in the constructor if it is null just to see it is displaying.

I can post all the code if needed but there's a lot unrelated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here isn't the `static` modifier, it's the `reRender` attribute.

The reRender attribute is causing an ajax postback to take place but then nothing is rerendered because the value in the attribute isn't valid for any element in the page.

If you remove the rerender attribute entirely, the whole page will refresh. If you add an ID to one of your tags and then place that ID in the rerender attribute, it'll do a postback and then a partial page refresh of the markup within that element.

```
<apex:page id="thePage" controller="TestPageController">

    <apex:form id="mySweetForm">

        Radius: 

        <apex:selectList value="{!distance}" multiselect="false" size="1">
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!distList}" ></apex:selectOptions>  
            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" oncomplete="initialize();" reRender="mySweetForm" />
        </apex:selectList>

        {!distance}

    </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

Comment: Mark is mentioning `static` perhaps because of my wrong answer that I have now deleted.

Comment: It does need to be stateful though...`static` modifier should not work here.

Comment: The `static` modifier does work in this case. It didn't change page behavior in any way. That said, it's unnecessary and shouldn't be there but that wasn't the root problem.

Comment: Mark, that's great. I can actually see the value going somewhere now. But if I reRender just the form the value remains the previous value for the rest of the page. While If I reload the page the other Controller values seem to be wiped out.
The aim is to use this distance value in a javascript funciton which is calling it from the Controller.

Comment: I don't know what the rest of your page controller looks like but if you've got `static` modifiers on other attributes, remove them. I would also suggest that you get back to basics in the VF markup by removing the "fancier" enhancements like partial page postbacks with rerenders until you get a page that behaves properly in a full-postback and full-page-refresh scenario. After you've got a working page, add back in the cool stuff.